# JavaFX does not repaint when removing an object drawn on top of another object

Tags: javafx, rendering

In the code below, the green rectangle is not removed on mouse click. However, if you resize the stage after the mouse click, the scene is repainted and the green rect vanishes.

If you set the green rectangle's size to 150/150, then some of it is immediately on top of the pane, and it vanishes immediately on mouse click.

- Is this a JavaFX bug, or am I overlooking something?
- How can I make the rectangle disappear on mouse click?

My environment: Windows 7 / Java 1.8.0 64-Bit Server VM build 25.0-b70.

```
package xschach.client;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main3 extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(Main3.class.getName());
    }

    public Main3() {}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 200);
        pane.getChildren().add(rect);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 300, 300));
        stage.show();

        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50);
        rect2.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        pane.getChildren().add(rect2);

        pane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> pane.getChildren().remove(rect2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a workaround for the problem: In the start method, create a 0-sized Rectangle. In the event handler, additionally first remove then add that rectangle. It seems that adding the rectangle of size 0 forces a repaint. By removing it first, we make sure we can click multiple times. ... Yes, and this works better than first adding then removing it in the event handler :(

Comment: I agree with José, this definitely seems like a bug, please report it in the [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/).

Comment: Georg, @jewelsea, so has anyone reported this to the JavaFX team?

Comment: I saw a JavaFX bug report from 2014. It has several comments but is still open.

Comment: There is a bug in openjdk about this and it's still open:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087752

Comment: @Hosseinmp76 Thanks for providing the link - this is the bug I have reported in 2014...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really seems to me a bug.

Doing some tests, what happens is the very last node (on top), no matter how many we have, that lays within the bounds of the first one, when it's removed, it is not visible to the scene graph, it's not marked as dirty, and no `requestLayout()` is called.

I've found also other workaround. Just allow some (minimal) transparency to the first child, and it will work...

```
rect.setFill(Color.web("000000FE"));
```

And you can always put this node behind the first one...

```
pane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
     rect2.toBack();
     pane.getChildren().remove(rect2);
});
```

Anyway, consider filing a bug to Jira.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little bit late, but it might help someone.

If you use the method `.clear()` on the children list of the `pane` if forces the render of the view.
So this solution, quite extreme, I admit it, works :

```
pane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
       pane.getChildren().clear();
       pane.getChildren().add(rect);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another workaround. Move the node that is not erasing to the back with the `toBack()` method, and then move it back to its place with the `toFront()` method. This seems to activate the dirty mechanism and repaints the background node correctly.